# How to re-calculate a Google Sheet every time a Google Forms questionnaire is submitted?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I used Google Forms to create a questionnaire, and I created a formula for Google Forms answers using Google Scripts.

After that, I want to re-record the calculated result on the Google Sheet every time the questionnaire is done.

How can I trigger such a recalculation?

Comment: post a script you used and share a link to copy of your sheet

Comment: Many formulas are recalculated every time that a cell value changes. What is the formula that you want to be recalculated on each form submission?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your script actively updates your spreadsheet. It will *not* work if you use your script as a formula (e.g. by putting `=myScript()` in a cell).

An example script that will work, by updating a cell in your spreadsheet with the current date:

```
function runThisOnFormSubmission() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());
}
```

To set up a trigger for the script, so that it will actually run on form submission:

1. In the script editor, go to *Edit → Current project's triggers*.
2. Click the *Add Trigger* button (lower right corner of the screen)
3. A form pops up. Select:

   - Choose which function to run: (your function)
   - Choose which deployment to run: Head
   - Select event source: From spreadsheet
   - Select event type: On form submit
4. You will be asked to grant permission to your script
5. From now on, your script will be run when the form is submitted

To demonstrate this, I have set up [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_aCh5TZ54SNpCPuC89KxfXMzAtVS_ZCwboa3IDG3Q-M/edit?usp=sharing) and connected [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1FNAgzs7AmicHX0cPD5eR2TEbGZEgWVaZY6KNSEi58lM/edit?usp=sharing). Feel free to copy them and experiment with them.